# POSTGIS - find whether given point(lon, lat) is within geography column (representation of polygon) of table

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

QN: Am getting error from ST_Within function for the geometry supplied in PostGIS. Not sure on what is the rite way to implement first argument of ST_Within.

Note: variables longitude and latitude are of character type supplied to function. However, I am not able to construct the value passed to ST_Within.

extract of code from custom function:

```
pointText := 'POINT(longitude ||   || latitude )';
result := (select p_code 
           from public.parking_lot 
           b where ST_Within (ST_GeomFromText(pointText)::geometry::geography,wkb_geography) limit 1);
```

EDIT: 14TH Nov 2019
With @jim-jones suggestion, I have re-created my function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.returnParkingLot(
    longitude character,
    latitude character)
  RETURNS character AS
$BODY$  
declare result text;
declare pointText text;
BEGIN
    IF longitude = '0' THEN
        return '';
    ELSE

        pointText := 'POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')';

        result := (select p_code from public.parking_lot b where ST_Within (ST_GeomFromText(pointText),b.wkb_geography::GEOMETRY) limit 1);
        return result;
    END IF;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.returnParkingLot(character, character)
  OWNER TO mother;
```

Access: 
I use the above function using select statement as follows:

```
select public.returnParkingLot('103.84472222','1.28333333');
```

Notes: Wish to know whether this implementation is right.

Edit: 21st Nov

As requested by @jim-jones, changes to datatype of inputs from user below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.returnParkingLot(
    longitude double precision,
    latitude double precision)
  RETURNS character AS
$BODY$  
declare result text;
declare pointText text;
BEGIN
    IF longitude = '0' THEN
        return '';
    ELSE

        pointText := 'POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')';

        result := (select p_code from public.parking_lot b where ST_Within (ST_GeomFromText(pointText),b.wkb_geography::GEOMETRY) limit 1);
        return result;
    END IF;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.returnParkingLot(double precision, double precision)
  OWNER TO mother;
```

Select statement:

```
select public.returnParkingLot(103.84472222, 1.28333333);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a) `pointText` contains valid numeric parameters and b) `wkb_geography` is indeed of type geography, we can assume that the problem is the parameters data type. According to the documentation [`ST_Within`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) expects `geometry`. You might wanna try this out:

```
SELECT p_code 
FROM public.parking_lot b 
WHERE ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)'),b.wkb_geography::GEOMETRY);
```

Your function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.returnParkingLot(
  longitude NUMERIC,
  latitude NUMERIC) RETURNS character AS
$BODY$  
DECLARE result text;
DECLARE pointText text;
BEGIN
IF longitude = '0' THEN
  RETURN '';
ELSE
  pointText := 'POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')';
  result := (SELECT p_code FROM public.parking_lot b 
     WHERE ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText(pointText),b.wkb_geography::GEOMETRY) LIMIT 1);
  RETURN result;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT COST 100;
```

Test:

```
CREATE TABLE parking_lot (p_code INT, wkb_geography GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO parking_lot VALUES (1,'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))');
SELECT public.returnParkingLot(30, 11);

 returnparkinglot 
------------------
 1
(1 Zeile)
```

**Side note:**
Do you really need this much precision to locate a parking lot? With eight decimal places you're almost in the microscopy realm.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I have edited the qn to include my amendment to how lon,lat is supplied to function. Kindly let know whether this would be the right implementation. Thanks.

Comment: It seems okay to me. I'm just not so sure about the data types of the parameters. You declared them as character and they should be numeric. To avoid exceptions, I'd suggest to change these data types:

Comment: I have tried replacing the input datatype to double precision, but still no result is returned for given inputs. But the data exists in given table column. Besides ST_Within, which other function would be useful in returning row of data where given point falls in the geography column?

Comment: ST_Within should actually do the job. Can you show how your function looks like now?

Comment: I have added the edits under 21st Nov above. Kindly check it. Thanks. alot.

Comment: @shiva just changed my answer. Change your datatype to numeric instead of double precision and you should be fine.

Comment: your solution works. I am not able to upvote it though! Thanks alot!!!